# What's the best practice to enforce a foreign key constraint through a REST API?

Tags: python, postgresql, rest, flask, sqlalchemy

I am making a to-do list webapp as a hobby project using flask for the backend and a PostgreSQL database to store the data. The database model is a as follows:

**models.py**

```py
class Group(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "groups"
    group_id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True)


class Collection(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "collections"
    collection_id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True)
    group_name = db.Column(db.String(20), db.ForeignKey("groups.name"), nullable=True)

    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            "collection_id": self.collection_id,
            "name": self.name,
            "group_name": self.group_name,
        }


class Task(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "tasks"
    task_id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    text = db.Column(db.String(200))
    completed = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    collection_name = db.Column(
        db.String(20), db.ForeignKey("collections.name"), nullable=False
    )

    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            "task_id": self.task_id,
            "text": self.text,
            "completed": self.completed,
            "collection_name": self.collection_name,
        }
```

While making the REST api logic for adding tasks to the database, I was unsure if:

- I should check if the `collection_name` column already exists in the `collections` table before trying to insert the data in the database.
- I should try inserting the row anyway and catch the `sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError` exception if it happens.

The problem I see with the first solution, is I need to query the `collections` tables for the list of valid `collection_name` each time I want to add a task, which I am not sure if it's a good practice performance wise.

While the problem I see with the second solution is that the `sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError` exception is pretty vague and in a more sophisticated table with several foreign keys, I would need to parse the exception's message to know which foreign key was violated.

For now, I implemented the second solution because I have a very simple table with only one foreign key constraint.

In the following you can see the code for the `controller.py` that handles the API call and `service.py` that talks with the database.

**controller.py**

```py
@tasks_api.route(COMMON_API_ENDPOINT + "/tasks", methods=["POST"])
def add_task():
    request_body = request.get_json()

    # Check for missing fields in the call
    mandatory_fields = set(["text", "collection_name"])
    try:
        missing_fields = mandatory_fields - set(request_body.keys())
        assert len(missing_fields) == 0
    except AssertionError:
        return (
            jsonify(
                {
                    "error": "The following mandatory fields are missing: "
                    + str(missing_fields)
                }
            ),
            400,
        )

    # Try to call the add task service function
    try:
        task = TaskService.add_task(
            text=request_body["text"], collection_name=request_body["collection_name"]
        )
    except CollectionNotFoundError as e:
        return jsonify({"error_message": str(e)}), 400
    else:
        return (
            jsonify(
                {
                    "result": "A new task was created successfully.",
                    "description": task.to_dict(),
                }
            ),
            201,
        )
```

**service.py**

```py
def add_task(text: str, collection_name: str) -> Task:
    try:
        with get_session() as session:
            task = Task(text=text, collection_name=collection_name)
            session.add(task)
            return task
    except sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError:
        raise CollectionNotFoundError(
            "Foreign key violation: There is no collection with the name "
            + collection_name
        )
```

While writing this post, I wondered if this is an XY problem where both solutions are not the best. I am open to other suggestions too.

Thanks !